# .pct_change() in infinite while loop starting with an empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I am trying to get an output with 2 columns.
The first column "close" should be the actual stockprice which is requested from the web.
I already got this

The second column "change" should be the percentage change between the prices in the first column.
Of course always in comparison with the previous row.

What does need to be changed to get this?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd


def priceTracker():
    url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL"
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
    price = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "D(ib) Mend(20px)"})[0].find("span").text
    return (price)

results = []
   
i = 1

while i == 1:
    results.append(priceTracker())
    df = pd.DataFrame(results)
    df.columns = ["close"]

    if len(df.index) >5:
            print(df.tail(3))
            #print(df["close"].pct_change()) --> NOT WORKING
```

Comment: Can you share some more details about the purpose of the `while` loop? Do you, say, want to have 5 prices, add them to a dataframe, show the percentage change, and stop or are you trying to achieve something else?

Comment: It is an infinite loop beacause I want it as a realtime-monitoring. I print only the tail, because i only need to see the last 3 or so prices and didnt want to print out the whole and very long df

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the data type to float on the close column.

```
while i == 1:
    results.append(priceTracker())
    df = pd.DataFrame(results)
    df.columns = ["close"]
    df['close'] = df['close'].astype('float')  #<<<<<<<added this

    if len(df.index) >5:
            print(df.tail(3))
            #print(df["close"].pct_change())
```